# Remove digits/numbers from a string

Tags: vb.net

I am working on one task (related to vb.net) where I need to get only text but no digits in it.

For example I am getting the value
"0196 CARPORT" but instead of this I need to get "CARPORT" to make my condition satisfied.

Could someone please help me in achieving this . Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Regex to remove all numbers like this.

Regex.Replace(theString, "\d", String.Empty).Trim()

Comment: Thank You very much for the quick response, I really appreciate your guidance. May I know whether this snippet removes the space between 0196 and CARPORT?? Since the number 0196 will be removed what about the space infront of CARPORT ??

Comment: Yes, that's what Trim() at the end does.  You'll want to assign it back to your variable as well.  So if your variable was "theString", the full statement would be:

theString = Regex.Replace(theString, "\d", String.Empty).Trim()

Comment: Hi Paul , Thank you for your support it's working extraordinary well.

Comment: Kindly help me with one more scenario please.  I have a text "RESIDENTIAL_GARAGE{173}" but I need to get  "RESIDENTIAL GARAGE" . Please help me with this . Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Two options...
If you want to replace every underscore with a space, then:
   theString = theString.Replace("_", " ")
If you want to also take into account that multiple underscores should become a single space, then this works in all cases, but is slower:
  theString = Regex.Replace(theString, "_+", " ")

Comment: Thank you , the second function did the job .